# How can I stop processing of further events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, invoke

Similar to the KeyPress events, I want whoever is subscribed to the event to be able to set e.Handled in my EventArgs class. If they return true, I no longer want to continue firing events. Any ideas how to implement this? Right now, here is my method:

```
protected void OnDataReceived(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataReceived != null)
    {                
        DataReceived(this, e);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, everybody who is subscribed to the event will receive notification, so setting e.Handled = true; will have no effect here.

Comment: I think you have been trapped by the listener pattern in this instance.  Do you control all the code?

Comment: Right now I have control of all of the code, but as I am implementing a Plugin model I might not in the future. Essentially I have an event, and the first plugin to handle that event, I don't want any other plugins to perform any additional processing on it. Some events I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample code for a solution using [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist(loband).aspx):

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomeEvent;

    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        var listeners = SomeEvent.GetInvocationList();
        foreach (var listener in listeners)
        {
            if (e.Handled) break;
            ((EventHandler<MyEventArgs>)listener).Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```